# How do I pass a parameter to my url for a POST function that takes a string parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http

I'm using ASP.NET Core for a Web API and created a POST function and don't know how to pass a string "name" in the URL such that the function can return the correct string.

The url should be :

https://localhost/44320/api/

```
//This is in my Controller class
[HttpPost("test/{name}")]
public string PostTest(string name)
{
    return "Name: " + name;
}
```

The return value is self explanatory but I just get a 405 error for when I do
https://localhost:44320/api/test/bob/

Comment: I think you need to decorate the `name` parameter with the `[FromRoute]` attribute.

Comment: Put it in the  parameter, before string name but still doesn't work. I tried:
https://localhost:44320/api/list/test/bob...
https://localhost:44320/api/list/test/name=bob...
https://localhost:44320/api/list/test/{name=bob}

Comment: What changes should I make to the code above to make that work?

Comment: How you are sending the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure your controller looks as follows:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ListController : Controller
{        
    [HttpPost("test/{name}")]
    public string Post([FromRoute] string name)
    {
        return "Name: " + name;
    }
}
```

Put a breakpoint on the `return` statement, debug the application, and then send a POST request to it using: https://localhost:44320/api/list/test/bob

`name` should then contain the value `bob`.

Edit: Here's a working screenshot of the above, although the localhost port is obviously different.

[image: successful-post-api-call]

Comment: Tried going through the debugger with it but name doesn't have a value yet. How would you write a function to simply return the value of a string paremeter with POST?

Comment: @peakednoob I've added the full controller for you to see.

Comment: This essentially worked, I don't have postman but when I changed the HttpPost to HttpGet, it worked in the visual studio debugger and when I ran it normally. Not sure why I had to make that change though. Either way, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("test/{name}")]
```